# Setting points and doing a quick "snip", dynamically playing the video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor

I need to cut out "best moments" from 1hour videos.(up to 6 moments per video)

What software is able to set in/out marks and save marked periods with keyboard shortcuts while watching the main video?

I'm thinking to make a bash script where I type in:

> "02.22 04.44 clipName"

then it will execute a command:

> ffmpeg -ss 00.02.22 -to 00.04.44 -i longVideo.mp4 -c copy
> clipName.mp4

Answer (score 0):

The exact software I was looking for
https://mifi.github.io/lossless-cut

Please donate to the author if you can and will use it, his soft saved my hobby gaming youtube channel and lots of free time)